# use of ! in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

I am new to ruby! And i am trying to learn the use of "!" .

I am aware that ! is included to  so that the user's string is modified in-place; otherwise, Ruby will create a copy of user_input and modify that instead.

But in the following case for both the programs i am getting the same output.Why?

```
print "Please Enter your Input"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

print "Please Enter your Input"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase
```

Comment: Where are you printing the string?

Comment: I get a [different ouput](https://gist.github.com/dmke/d9adb8729e8623d86820) (on the same input). (yes, I know, I should update my Ruby installation ;-))

Comment: Also note that `!` really means "danger". It's used when the object is modified, or when the operation has other non-obvious side-effects. For example, in Rails, `save!` means "throw an error if the save has a problem", while `save` just returns false if there is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby, bangs (!) are used to inform the programmer that the method they are calling is `destructive`. It's Ruby's way of saying "Hey! This method is going to change the object it is called on!". A number of safe methods in the `String`, `Array,`Enumerable`, etc classes have destructive counterparts.

Example:

```
my_str = "Hello, World!"
my_str.downcase # => "hello, world!"
my_str # => "Hello, World!"

my_str = "Goodbye, World!"
my_str.downcase! # => "goodbye, world!"
my_str #> "goodbye, world!"
```

As you can see, while both methods return the string's lower case variant, `downcase!` actually changes `my_str` permanently.

It's a very convenient aspect of Ruby that I wish more languages offered.

I think it's also worth mentioning that, because destructive methods work in-place, they are generally faster and more memory efficient than their safe counterparts who have to return new objects. Therefore, `my_string.downcase!` should be preferred to `my_string = my_string.downcase` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "Please Enter your Input"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
```

`user_input` value is what the user entered, in lowercase

```
print "Please Enter your Input"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase
```

`user_input` value is what the user entered

The difference resides in the value of `user_input`, not in what gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods behave the same, but the returned objects are different.

`downcase`returns a modified copy of `user_input`. In other words, `user_input` stays the same.

`downcase!` returns `user_input` modified. Note that this can be more memory efficient, since you don't generate a copy of `user_input`.

In both cases, they return a downcase version of `user_input`. That's why you have the same output.

To learn more about bang methods in Ruby, see this [blog post](http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist).

hth